# Access Parent Page Property from User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Trying to access a property from the parent page on my user control.

Here's the start of my default.asp codebehind:

```
Partial Class _Default
     Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

     Private _selectedID As String = "74251BK3232"

     Public Property SelectedID() As String
          Get
               Return _selectedID 
          End Get
          Set(ByVal value As String)
               _selectedID = value
          End Set
     End Property
```

Here's the start of my user control codebehind:

```
Partial Class ctrlAddAttribute
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
     Dim selectedID As String = Me.Parent.Page.selectedID()
```

I'm getting the error "selectedID is not a member of System.Web.UI.Page"

Please adivse!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could access the property when you cast the Page to your actual implementaion called _Default.

```
Dim selectedID As String = DirectCast(Me.Page,_Default).selectedID()
```

But that is not the purpose of a Usercontrol(reusability).
Normally you would give the ID from the Controller(page) to the UserControl.

So define a property in the UserControl and set it from the page.
On this way the UserControl would still work in other pages.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I took your advice.  I added a public property to my control and set that from the page when I dynamically added it!

Answer (score 1):

Because the user control doesn't belong to the page, you can't access it directly unless you either explicitly set a property in the usercontrol from the including page or create a recursive function that cycles through all of the parent objects until it finds an object of type `System.Web.UI.Page`.

For the first, you could use a property (I've done this using a property called `ParentForm`) in the user control:

```
Private _parentForm as System.Web.UI.Page
Public Property ParentForm() As System.Web.UI.Page  ' or the type of your page baseclass
    Get
        Return _parentForm
    End Get
    Set
        _parentForm = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In the "Parent" page, you would set this property in an event as early as possible. I prefer to use PreLoad because it comes before the load (thus is available when most other controls would need it) and after the init.

```
Protected Sub Page_PreLoad(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Me.PreLoad
    Me.myUserControlID.ParentForm = Me
End Sub
```

You could also write a function trolls through the parent controls to find the page. Following code is untested so it may require tweaking, but the idea is sound.

```
Public Shared Function FindParentPage(ByRef ctrl As Object) As Page
    If "System.Web.UI.Page".Equals(ctrl.GetType().FullName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
        Return ctrl
    Else
        Return FindParentPage(ctrl.Parent)
    End If
End Function
```

EDIT: You also can't access this property directly because it does not exist within the type `System.Web.UI.Page`. As @Tim Schmelter recommends, you can either attempt to cast the page to the specific page type `_Default` or if this is something common to many of your pages, you may need to create a base page class and include your property in that class. Then you can inherit this class instead of System.Web.UI.Page

```
Public Class MyBasePage
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Property SelectedID() as Integer
        ...
    End Property
End Class
```

Then in the page:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits MyBasePage

    ...

End Class
```